# Quaternions no Unity3D

Tags: c#, matemática, unity3d

Bom... gostaria de saber mais sobre Quaterniões na Unity... não entendi muito bem o que fazem... e porque usam os Quaterniões e não os Ângulos De Euler... não achei material bom sobre isso, até achei sobre os Quaterniões em si, mas não sobre os Quaterniões inseridos na Unity... não tenho um conhecimento extremamente avançado em matemática, então procurem explicar de uma maneira simplificada... obrigado...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não entendo sobre o assunto, mas acho interessante, então fiz uma pesquisa e vou colocar o que achei aqui, com as fontes.

Da documentação do Unity3D:

> [Unity - Scripting API: **Quaternion**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html)
>
> Quaternions são usados para representar rotações.
>
> Eles são compactos, não sofrem com a [trava do gimbal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) (*gimbal lock*) e podem ser facilmente interpolados. Unity usa internamente Quaternions para representar todas as rotações.
>
> Eles são baseados em números complexos e não são fáceis de entender intuitivamente. Você quase nunca acessa ou modifica componentes individuais do Quaternion (x, y, z, w); na maioria das vezes você simplesmente pegaria as rotações existentes (por exemplo, da classe [Transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html)) e as usaria para construir novas rotações (por exemplo, para interpolar suavemente entre duas rotações). As funções da estrutura Quaternion que você usa 99% do tempo são: [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html), [Quaternion.Angle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Angle.html), [Quaternion.Euler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html), [Quaternion.Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html), [Quaternion.FromToRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) e [Quaternion.identity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-identity.html). (As outras funções são apenas para usos exóticos).

Do Stack Overflow (inglês):

> [Quaternions vs. Euler Angles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6002516/8133067)
>
> Os ângulos de Euler são mais compreensíveis para os seres humanos e também bons para decompor rotações em graus individuais de liberdade (para articulações cinemáticas e similares), mas apresentam desvantagens como a ambiguidade e a trava do gimbal. Na prática eu preferiria Quaternions, já que eles são mais fáceis de serem computados (para o computador, não para humanos) e mais eficientes. Você tem que fazer três rotações e multiplicá-las juntas ao girar pelos ângulos de Euler, enquanto que com um Quaternion apenas uma rotação é necessária, e como ela já codifica o seno e cosseno, a conversão de Quaternion para matriz é bastante eficiente.

Do site de Perguntas e Respostas do Unity:

> [Quando usar Quartenion vs Ângulos de Euler?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/765683/when-to-use-quaternion-vs-euler-angles.html) (*When to use Quaternion vs Euler Angles?*)
>
> *Pergunta:*
>   Esta é uma questão de "melhores práticas", bem como uma questão de esclarecimento. Eu entendo que os ângulos de Euler são uma maneira de ler Quaternions como um valor vector3, mas quando você iria querer usar Ângulos de Euler? Por que não usar Quaternions o tempo todo?
>
> *Resposta:*
>   Quaternions têm algumas vantagens quando se trata da trava do gimbal e interpolação suave. Sua principal desvantagem é que eles dependem de matemática avançada -- matemática que mesmo os desenvolvedores experientes com frequência acham difícil e confusa.
>
> As pessoas raramente interagem com os Quaternions diretamente. Como se constata, é quase sempre mais fácil manipulá-los usando outras representações:
>
> - A representação ângulo-eixo especifica um vetor unitário e uma rotação sobre esse vetor (consulte as páginas ToAngleAxis e AngleAxis).
> - A representação do ângulo de Euler especifica a rotação em torno dos eixos Z, X e Y, nessa ordem (consulte as páginas eulerAngles e Euler).
>
> O manual do script sugere alguns dos truques mais comuns para manipular ou gerar Quaternions.
>
> Existem alguns artigos acadêmicos na internet, se você quiser entender mais sobre a matemática por trás dos Quaternions. Se você planeja usá-los muito, eu recomendo altamente que você pelo menos passe de leve por alguns.
>
> Recomendo usar variáveis ​​de Quaternion para representar duas coisas: a rotação de um objeto e/ou uma rotação que você gostaria de aplicar a algum objeto. Mesmo quando usados para esse propósito, é quase sempre mais fácil gera-los usando os métodos descritos acima, ou pegando um Quaternion existente e girando-o por algum valor que você acabou de gerar.
>
> É muito raro que você precise examinar ou manipular ativamente Quaternions que não foram criados por você mesmo. Geralmente, é mais fácil usar a matemática vetorial para resolver problemas, incluindo o uso inteligente de produtos escalar e vetorial.

Dos comentários à resposta acima:

> Use um Quaternion para copiar uma rotação:
>
> ```
> Quaterion myQuaterion = transform.rotation;
> otherTransform.rotation = myQuaterion;
> ```
>
> Use ângulos de Euler para alterar ou configurar uma nova rotação:
>
> ```
> rotation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 30, 0);
> ```
>
> No momento em que você tiver um PhD em matemática para usar Quaternions diretamente, você não estará mais interessado em escrever jogos.
>
> Muito difícil definir um ângulo específico com um Quaternion.
>   Ambos têm aplicações diferentes. Eu costumo usar eulerAngles com muito mais frequência do que os Quaternions.